# Share articles on linkedin not working with new v2 Api's

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, linkedin-api

We have an app where we are using social media share with **Linkedin**, earlier the app was using `v1` Api and post share was working fine, but now all of the sudden it has stopped working. I checked on google seems like `v1` Apis  are now deprecated, so I tried using v2 api's. But now I am getting below error-:

> Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request
>   failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request
>   failed: forbidden (403)

Below is the code where I am passing access permissions and all other parameters for getting access token.

```
 - (LIALinkedInHttpClient *)client {
        UIViewController *top = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
      //  [top presentViewController:secondView animated:YES completion: nil];

        LIALinkedInApplication *application = [LIALinkedInApplication applicationWithRedirectURL:@"https://com.xxxxxx.linkedin.oauth/oauth"
clientId:@"xxxxxxxxx"
clientSecret:@"xxxxxxxx"
state:@"xxxxxxxxx"                                                                                      
grantedAccess:@[@"w_member_social"]];

        return [LIALinkedInHttpClient clientForApplication:application presentingViewController:top.presentedViewController]; //[LIALinkedInHttpClient clientForApplication:application];
    }
```

**v2 URL** - : `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/shared?/accessToken`, here `accessToken` is the valid token value which is appended to the URL, when I check the value in console.

I am not getting how to make a valid request with v2 Api's, or if there are more parameters that we need to pass for new Api's, can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Kindly let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: That is objective-c code, maybe you should change your tags for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [LinkedIn Share API v2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#post-shares), your HTTP call should be looked like this:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares
```

json:

```
{
    "content": {
        "contentEntities": [
            {
                "entityLocation": "https://www.example.com/content.html",
                "thumbnails": [
                    {
                        "resolvedUrl": "https://www.example.com/image.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "title": "Test Share with Content"
    },
    "distribution": {
        "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
    },
    "owner": "urn:li:person:324_kGGaLE",
    "subject": "Test Share Subject",
    "text": {
        "text": "Test Share!"
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tested with this URL?

Comment: The json body is actual server response? or is it a parameter body structure that we need to pass while making a call?

Comment: it is the parameter body structure that we need to pass while making a call, not the response.